# How to Reproduce Hypertools Clusters Identified from Hypertools.plot

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-science, hypertools

[Hypertools](https://hypertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) seems like a great toolset for analyzing some high dimensional data quickly.

In particular, you can take some data, throw it in `hypertools.plot(...)` and get something nice looking out.

However, I'm having trouble reproducing the groups afterward.

In theory, `hypertools.plot(data, reduce="alg", cluster="alg2")` should be roughly equivalent to:

```
data = np.array(...)
reduced = hypertools.analyze(data, reduce="alg")
labels = hypertools.cluster(reduced, cluster="alg2")
hypertools.plot(reduced, hue=labels)
```

But I'm seeing wildly different labels from the step-by-step approach compared to `hypertools.plot(...)`.

Is there a way to get the same clusters out without plotting? Can I extract the clusters from the return value of `hypertools.plot(..)` (not preferred as sometimes my Python doesn't realize the plot has been closed so the return value is never realized)?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `hypertools.plot` source code, it looks like the issue is the fact that mixing `reduce` and `cluster` inside the same call to `plot` reduces to at most three dimensions first, if smaller is not specified, then clusters. When you take the step-by-step approach, the dimensionality is not reduced to three until you plot after you have already clustered. Limiting the dimensions with `ndims=3` in the `analyze` function of step-by-step approach produces the same results as the one-liner you want.

So the answer to your question 'Is there a way to get the same clusters out without plotting?' would be to pass `ndims=3` to the `analyze` function.

From `plot.py` (hypertools v0.6.2):

```
# reduce data to 3 dims for plotting, if ndims is None, return this
    if (ndims and ndims < 3):
        xform = reducer(xform, ndims=ndims, reduce=reduce, internal=True)
    else:
        xform = reducer(xform, ndims=3, reduce=reduce, internal=True)

    # find cluster and reshape if n_clusters
    if cluster is not None:
        if hue is not None:
            warnings.warn('cluster overrides hue, ignoring hue.')
        if isinstance(cluster, (six.string_types, six.binary_type)):
            model = cluster
            params = default_params(model)
        elif isinstance(cluster, dict):
            model = cluster['model']
            params = default_params(model, cluster['params'])
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid cluster model specified; should be'
                             ' string or dictionary!')

        if n_clusters is not None:
            if cluster in ('HDBSCAN',):
                warnings.warn('n_clusters is not a valid parameter for '
                              'HDBSCAN clustering and will be ignored.')
            else:
                params['n_clusters'] = n_clusters

        cluster_labels = clusterer(xform, cluster={'model': model,
                                               'params': params})
        xform, labels = reshape_data(xform, cluster_labels, labels)
        hue = cluster_labels
```

Example using the **mushroom** sample data set:

```
import hypertools
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

geo = hypertools.load('mushrooms')
data = geo.get_data()
reduced = hypertools.analyze(data, ndims=3, reduce="SparsePCA")
labels = hypertools.cluster(reduced, cluster="Birch")
hypertools.plot(reduced, '.', hue=labels)
```

[image]

Gives the same results as:

```
hypertools.plot(data, '.', reduce="SparsePCA", cluster="Birch")
```

[image]

Compared to step-by-step without passing `ndims=3` to `analyze`:
[image]